# Regarding PopupMenu

Tags: android

I have a popup menu...
I need to disable the options from the popup menu on some condition. Could anyone please tell me how???

```
final ImageButton imgbutton = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        imgbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, v);
                popup.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu);
                popup.show();
                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        Toast.makeText(context,
                                "You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    }
                });

            }
        });
```

Comment: at what condition you want to disable some options??

Comment: Depends on the click is on Files/ Folder

Comment: What is your condition to show popup? Place the condition using **if** before popup.show()

Comment: When i click on the button the menu shows RENAME, PRPERTIES, MOVE, SHARE in pop up. What i need is that if i click on the FOLDER i need rename, Properties on the popup others should hide

Comment: @Anand: Use setTag method

Comment: Could you please tell me how???

Comment: @Anand then you should add condition and set to different popup_menu layout at popup.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your if condition just enable or disable any option you want ....

```
 popup.getMenu().getItem(position_of_menuItem).setEnabled(false);
```

Hope it helps..!

Comment: First index should be 0..then 1 ...2...3......................first try to disable at 0 position without condition..

Comment: But it still there as disabled. but i dont need it to show there

Comment: your question was " I need to disable the options from the popup menu on some condition"........

Comment: In this case you can try............    popup.getMenu().getItem(1).setVisible(false);